# Cumulative probability of independent events with unequal credibility

Tags: probability

I want to find the cumulative probability of at least 1 out of let's say 3 independent events having unequal probabilities of occurrence. For example, I am playing n=3 different games and I have the following probabilities to win in each game p = [.2 .3 .4]. What is the cumulative probability of me winning in at least 1 of these games?

The binomial formula for cumulative probabilities $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ doesn't work for me since the probabilities of each event are different.

Comment: Hint: What's the probability of losing all three games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

probability of winning at least $1$ game is equal to $1 - P(\text{winning no game})$

You just have to compute $ P(\text{winning no game})$ and use $1$ to subtract it.

Comment: So, if I got it right, I have to find the probability of all three events not happening and then subtract 1. In my previous example, that'd be $1-(1-p1) * (1-p2) * (1-p3)$.
Thanks!

Comment: yes, that is right.